# PTIJ: Gingerbread man during Pesach

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

How does the gingerbread man deal with the Issur of Chametz on Pesach, if he's made of leavened flour? Does he sell himself to a Goy? Doesn't this defeat the purpose of being free on Pesach, of Cheirus?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: It's assur to sell oneself to a goy. Perhaps the Pesach conondrum is what inspired him to run away!

Comment: He has to be a self-hating chew.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apparently, you seem unfamiliar with the fairy tale of the [Ginger Bread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gingerbread_Man) man. The Ginger Bread man was eaten by a fox. I could almost guarantee that even if the gingerbread didn't have time to rise, a fox would eat him within 18 minutes.